# Bicategory of internal categories

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

On the [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+diagram) for internal diagrams, it's stated that given a finitely cocomplete category $\mathcal{C}$ we can form a bicategory $\mathsf{CAT}(\mathcal{C})$ of categories internal to $\mathcal{C}$ -- what exactly does this look like?

The objects of $\mathsf{CAT}(\mathcal{C})$ are presumably internal categories in $\mathcal{C}$, with morphisms between them being internal functors. What are the morphisms between parallel internal functors? Is $\mathsf{CAT}(\mathcal{C})$ a discrete bicategory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can form internal natural transformations between parallel internal functors.

For internal categories $X$ and $Y$ and internal functors $f, g: X \to Y$, an internal natural transformation $\alpha: f \to g$ is a map $\alpha: X_0 \to Y_1$ such that $src \circ a$ = $f_0$ and $tgt \circ a = g_0$ (intuitively, $\alpha$ is the map that takes an object $c$ to $\alpha_c: f(c) \to g(c)$). We also need this diagram to commute:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_1 @>{(g_1, \alpha \circ src)}>> Y_1 \times_{Y_0} Y_1\\
@V{(\alpha \circ tgt, f_1)}VV @VV{m}V \\
Y_1 \times_{Y_0} Y_1 @>>{m}> Y_1
\end{CD}
$$

where $m$ is the composition map. This diagram expresses naturality, which you can check by looking at the case internal to $\mathcal{Set}$.

Some more information can be found in [this (draft of a?) paper](https://ncatlab.org/davidroberts/files/internal_cats_and_anafunctors.pdf) by David Roberts.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated.